# Restructuring data (Variables to Cases) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got the following table:

```
ID    Var1   Var2   Var3
------------------------    
1      4      3      9
2      5      2      8
3      1      6      2
```

I would like to obtain the following table:

```
ID    Score     Variable
------------------------
1       4         Var1
1       3         Var2
1       9         Var3
2       5         Var1
2       2         Var2
2       8         Var3
3       1         Var1
3       6         Var2
3       2         Var3
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use union  all

```
    select  id, var1, score  'var1' variable
    from mytable
    union all  
    select  id, var2, 'var2' 
    from mytable
    union all  
    select  id, var3, 'var3' 
    from mytable
    order by  id, variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `cross apply` for this purpose:

```
select t.id, v.variable, v.score
from followingtable t cross apply
     (values ('var1', t.var1), ('var2', t.var2), ('var3', t.var3)) v(variable, score);
```

There are two other (obvious) ways to do this.  One uses `union all`.  This method has the advantage of only scanning the table once.  Hence, this version should be faster.  If your "table" is really a complicated subquery, the performance difference might be important.

Another method is `unpivot`.  The unpivot syntax (although standard) only handles one thing.  `cross apply` -- which implements standard *lateral* joins -- is much more powerful.  Unpivoting is just one of many ways that you can use the syntax.  And, it is an easy way to learn about lateral joins.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for Pivot/UnPivot...

```
create table #testing (id int, var1 int, var2 int, var3 int)
insert into #testing values (1,4,3,9);
insert into #testing values (2,5,2,8);
insert into #testing values (3,1,6,2);

select x.id, x.vars, x.val 
from #testing d
unpivot (val for vars in (var1, var2, var3)) as x
```

[image]

[image]